# How to get bootstrap to take whole screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-6

I created an app with rail6 and bootstrap 4.  The problem i have is that my website doesn't take up the whole screen.  There is a lot of white space on the top and the sides.  I don't know how to fix this. A live version of the website can be viewed here https://first-blog-001.herokuapp.com/.  You will immediately of what I'm talking about.

Here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Blog</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

  </head>

  <body class="d-flex flex-column">
    <%= render 'layouts/navigation'%>
    <div id="page-content">
          <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer'%>
  </body>
```

Here is my css.  I have tried making messing with margin: 0 and making the width 100% but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
@import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap';

.navbar {
    background-color: black !important;
}

.nav-link{
    color: white !important;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#home-container{
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.jumbotron{
    background-image: asset-url('jumboCopy.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 425px;
}

/* Sticky Footer Classes */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#page-content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#sticky-footer {
  flex-shrink: none;
}

/* Other Classes for Page Styling */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the website, apparently, the body has margin causes the issue.
Change `margin: 0` to the body should solve the issue, if not, adding `!important` should be ok.

```
body {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```